# dotnet run - angular - windows authentication - not authenticated

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

When running angular with:

> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.js

and .net core with:

> dotnet run

windows authentication never authenticate user.

However when running the application from Visual Studio F5 user is authenticated, (same port and everything).

**proxy.config.js**

```
const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

module.exports = {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:5000',
            secure: false,
            agent: new Agent({
                maxSockets: 100,
                keepAlive: true,
                maxFreeSockets: 10,
                keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                timeout: 6000000,
                keepAliveTimeout: 90000
            }),
            onProxyRes: proxyRes => {
                let key = 'www-authenticate';
                proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
                    proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
            }
        }
};
```

**iisSettings**

```
iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                    !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
                    !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            });

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            app.UseDefaultFiles();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
```

Why is that dotnet run and dotnet watch run doesn't work with windows authentication but Visual Studio F5 does?

**Update**

I have tried adding "weblistener" instead of enabling authentication in project properties. After adding weblistener I was able to authenticate using dotnet run but I could no longer start debugging using VS F5 for some reason...

```
.UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows authentication is not supported in dotnet cli if you're not using [HTTPSYS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys) or [Weblistener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth), (weblistener replaced with httpsys in 2.0?)

No Windows, no Windows auth.

I'm not sure how you're supposed to develop locally if you're publishing your app in IIS, (without httpsys or weblistener), (not supported in IIS).

I'm currently using IIS Express which is a pain in the butt.

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1432)

Answer (score 1):

If shortly: `dotnet run`starts the app without using IIS as a reverse proxy and so all your IIS settings are ignored

---

Your `launchSettings.json` where you have `iisSettings` section is used only when you run an app from Visual Studio.

> This json file holds project specific settings associated with each debug profile, Visual Studio is configured to use to launch the application, including any environment variables that should be used.

When you execute `dotnet run` command, [the Web Server (Kestrel by default) starts and hosts the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

When you launch the app from VS, also the IIS Express instance is configured to be a reverse proxy for your application. And this is enabling Windows Authentication.

Look into [IIS Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) for details how to configure IIS + ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: As I understand it, I have to use WebListener or IIS + Kestrel for windows authentication. I've tried weblistener but that wont allow me to debug using iis? Also I can't find a solution for dotnet run + iis. Do you know why I can't debug using weblistener and do you have a solution that works for both iis and dotnet run?

Comment: @Reft yes, Windows authentication can be configured for ASP.NET Core apps hosted with IIS or WebListener.  And WebListener can't be used with IIS or IIS Express, as it isn't compatible with the ASP.NET Core Module.  Look into [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth) - you may configure IIS site instead of using VS + IIS Express

Comment: Sorry but this does not help me. Once the app is deployed, windows authentication works as it should. The problem is when i develop locally. The app is hosted in iis, so I would like to develop using iis express and dotnet cli. I don't want to use httpsys in localhost. Using dotnet cli prevents me from using iis express? Am i forced to use visual studio instead of dotnet watch run?

Comment: @Reft have you found any solution to this? I am running into the same predicament.

Comment: @BurningHippo I've searched the entire internet for an answer but haven't found one yet.. Please let me know if you ever find a solution for this. Currently I'm using iis express instead of dotnet cli, which is horrible

Comment: @BurningHippo Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a response by David Fowler to similar issue.
Url: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpSysServer/issues/425

With those changes i am able to run in both Visual Studio and from dotnet run command.