# HttpContext.User.Identity not set when not using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I did a toy project with Visual Studio 2017 and ASP.NET Core 1.2, and I have some issues retrieving the user's WindowsIdentity when my project is executed as a standalone application, or in IIS 10 (WS2016), but works properly with IIS Express.

I keep using the same navigator, so I believe its configuration is correct.

I did a middleware :

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    var identity = context.User.Identity;

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(identity)) {
        string name = descriptor.Name;
        object value = descriptor.GetValue(identity);
        _logger.LogDebug("{0}={1}", name, value);
        // Displays IsAuthenticated=False, Name=(null), ...
    }

    var contextIdentity = context.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
    // Here contextIdentity is null
    ...
```

My launchSettings.json looks like :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:1028/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AVVC.UI.ASP.SMP.Proto.Secur.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my .csproj, I have added the following rules for the web.config :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="web.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <forwardWindowsAuthToken>True</forwardWindowsAuthToken>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And web.config is generated accordingly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\blehbleh.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for standalone application, as `launchSettings.json` file, where you have `iisSettings` section is used only when you run an app from Visual Studio.

> This json file holds project specific settings associated with each debug profile, Visual Studio is configured to use to launch the application, including any environment variables that should be used.

---

To fix the second issue with IIS 10, you need to setup Windows Authentication for your IIS site. From "Customize Authentication" section in [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth):

- disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication.

[image]

Also related SO: [dotnet run - angular - windows authentication - not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877365/dotnet-run-angular-windows-authentication-not-authenticated/45878521#45878521)

Comment: So it cannot work in standalone ? (I don't see how ...)

Comment: @willll not exactly. Windows authentication can be configured for ASP.NET Core apps hosted with IIS or WebListener So you can you can use WebListener (instead of Kestrel, that is used by default) to support self-hosted scenarios (but on Windows only). Look into linked documentation for setup instruction.

Comment: it started to work when I added services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => { options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true; }); in the ConfigureServices