# .Net Core CLI (dotnet myapp.dll) and Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am running my project from command line like below

```
dotnet "C:\MyApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyApp.dll" --environment "dev" --urls "http://localhost:6000" --ContentRoot "C:\MyApp\bin\Debug\net6.0"
```

The application is running fine except it doesn't set the user identity. I think it may be because it is completely ignoring the following iissettings.

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6000"
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to take care of it while the running project from command line (powershell)?

Here is a post I found about this.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877365/dotnet-run-angular-windows-authentication-not-authenticated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run the application self hosted by running it on Http.Sys server.Here is the code from Program.cs

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                .UseHttpSysIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
    public static class WebHostBuilderExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The purpose of this extension is to enable authentication when running from command line
        /// iissettings section in launchSettings.json is only used by Visual Studio
        /// </summary>
        public static IWebHostBuilder UseHttpSysIntegration(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var isSelfHosted = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RUN_SELFHOSTED");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(isSelfHosted) && isSelfHosted=="True")
            {
                // Self hosted
                builder.UseHttpSys(options =>
                {
                    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                });
            }
        return builder;
    }
```

When running the application using dotnet command, I also have to set the environment variable RUN_SELFHOSTED (a custom variable).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication,you could try :

```
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

When it comes to kestrel,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel)